# Permission to view custom html/aspx pages on modern Sharepoint site collection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

We have uploaded a few custom aspx pages, CSS and scripts within a folder in the Site Pages library on the modern site collection. Users with Owner or contribute access are able to access but visitors with Read access are not able to see the content on the aspx page.

What specific permissions should we grant to visitors to be able to access content on these pages?

Answer (score 0):

Users with read permission should be able to view pages and list items and download documents.

Did you set unique permission on these custom page?

Site Pages library > select custom page > Manage Access > Advanced

[Unique permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlzJQ.jpg)